# Microsoft Excel keeps repairing my .xlsm file for no apparent reason and eliminates data validations on a sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2019, excel-365

I recently created an automated Excel utility (using `Microsoft Office 2019`), in which I've extensively used data validations, VBA code, named ranges and formatting. It was working well until one day I received an Excel prompt message that read:

[image]

When I click on `Yes`, it gives me another pop-up where it says it recovered the file, and also gives me a link to the error log XML file. I click on it and open the .xml file using my default browser, and it shows the following details:

[image]

Looks like it is removing data validations from a particular sheet, and I realize that is true when I navigate to that sheet in the UI. To work around this unwarranted and repeated data-validation removal that Excel application is enforcing, I created a macro code that will re-instate all these data validations as required. The real problem arises when this Excel file is opened on a different computer with `Microsoft Office 365`. Looks like it is removing not just data-validations but also other components like named ranges and buttons. There could be other things that it might be removing, which I am unaware of at the moment. So the macro created to re-instate the data-validations is no longer useful.

Why does this problem arise? And why is different version of Excel behaving differently? How do I solve this? Appreciate your kind help. Thank you!

Comment: Are you set excel to save in a comparability mode. Look in settings.

Comment: @user14797724 I don't think it is being saved in compatibility mode. That setting is not checked true.

Comment: I had a similar problem years ago. A DV list was quite lengthy, and was created using VBA. The fix was to either put the list on a worksheet, and refer to the range, **OR** save the file as an `*.xlsb` file and **not** an `*.xlsm` file.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - will try the *.xlsb approach and let you know how it goes. Unfortunately I can't try the former given the requirement constraints. Thank you!

Comment: I had the same issue when my data validation lists were longer than the 255 characters. Remove/shorten this and it will disappear

Comment: @e_conomics thanks for that insight - didn't know that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rightly suggested by Ron Rosenfeld and e_conomics, the issue was with the data validation lists, whose sources were strings of comma separated values that were going beyond 255 characters. Apparently, that is a limitation with Excel.

When I replaced the sources of data validation lists (string of comma separated values) with the ranges containing the corresponding values, the problem resolved itself. The repair dialogue never appeared again.